# I want to paginate data. It is working fine but when I search for specific data it always shows in the first page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What I want is to paginate my data but the problem is when I'm searching for specific data if I'm on page 3 the result shows on page 1 always and I can't see anything because I was on page no 3. I want to go to page 1 automatically when I'm searching for something. Also when I press the next button if there is no data at all it still increases the page number.

Here is my code:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import UpdateDialogue from "./UpdateDialogue";

function List(props) {
  const API_URL = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";
  const [EmployeeData, setEmployeeData] = useState([]);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [postNumber] = useState(8);

  const currentPageNumber = pageNumber * postNumber - postNumber;

  const handlePrev = () => {
    if (pageNumber === 1) return;
    setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
  };
  const handleNext = () => {
    setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setEmployeeData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const filteredData = EmployeeData.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === "") {
      return el;
    } else {
      return el.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)
    }
  });

  const paginatedData = filteredData.splice(currentPageNumber, postNumber);
  
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        
        {paginatedData.map((user) => (
          <UpdateDialogue user={user} key={user.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>Page {pageNumber} </div>
      <div>
        <button style={{marginRight:10}} onClick={handlePrev}>prev</button>
        <button onClick={handleNext}>next</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Well I think for page number you can simply update the state of page using SetPageNumber(1) in search data and for next button you can disable that button on condition that is if pageNumber * itemNumber(shown in a page ) > data.length. Ex
<button onClick={handleNext} disabled={pageNumber * 10 > data.length}>next</button>

Also store the currentPageNumber as state only and set that to 1.

Comment: tried  SetPageNumber(1) but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with a useEffect on your input:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.input) {
    setPageNumber(1);
  }
}, [props.input]);
```

That way, whenever your input changes, your page number is set to 1.